# Delete blank highlighted rows after filtering it based on colour

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dataset which have quite a few blank highlighted rows.
I already recorded and got the script to help me delete the desired rows.

However as macros only recorded what you select, in the code it gives the row number i selected. Now this works if the row number always remains constant.
As data order can change now and then, i would like to know if rather that reference to a particular row the script would just automatically select the immediate row after the header.

This is the code. For the line 'rows(5:5).Select', the row number can keep changing.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$2000").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:=RGB(180, _
    180, 191), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
rows("5:5").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Comment: What do you exactly need to delete? what is the criteria for deleting rows?

Comment: The criteria is the cell color in that column which is in the code as RGB.
unfortunately the color in the sheet is not matching the 56 color codes for excel hence had to use RGB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the blank rows are the ones that are showing after filter, this will work.

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$2000")
    .AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:=RGB(180,180, 191), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
    On Error Resume Next 'only using this line in case there are no blank rows after filter
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    On Error Go To 0 'and now turn error reporting back on so any other errors fire as needed
End With
```

Comment: Scott,
Thanks! i thought of something like this but assumed that it wouldn't recognize blank cells as visible.
i changed the range from A1 to A2 to keep my header row intact.